# how to use Azure speech phonetic set for Japanese

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

this is for text to speech Azure service

how do I use the `sapi` phonetic alphabet set referenced here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-ssml-phonetic-sets#ja-jp

```
<phoneme alphabet="sapi" ph="">Akari</phoneme>
```

for example what do you put in ph for あかり

the doc gave some examples at the bottom e.g ゴ'ウセ but when i paste that i get
`SSML parsing error: 0x8004507A - Unknown phoneme`